# Free Finite Rank Abelian Group category is not balanced

Tags: category-theory

I'd like to prove (by finding a counterexample or whatever) that Free Finite Rank Abelian Group category is not balanced, i.e., a bimorphism doesn't imply isomorphism. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n>1$, show that multiplication by $n$ is a bimorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ but not an isomorphism.  (The hard part of this is showing it is epic; for this, you want to show that if $F$ is a free abelian group, then a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to F$ is uniquely determined by where it sends $n$.)

Comment: Yes but how do i do? I know if $f(n)=g(n)$, $f(z)=g(z)$ but why $f(n)=g(n)$?

Comment: If $n:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is multiplication by $n$ and $f\circ n=g\circ n$, then $f(n)=(f\circ n)(1)=(g\circ n)(1)=g(n)$.